# Lifetime Annotations for &str

Tags: rust

I'm a newbie to Rust and have been following the Rust Book to learn. In chapter 10.3, which discusses Lifetime Annotations for parameters in function signatures, the book mentions an example where the compiler is supposed to raise an error. The example is as follows

```
fn main() {
    let string1 = String::from("long string is long");
    let result;
    {
        let string2 = String::from("xyz");
        result = longest(string1.as_str(), string2.as_str());
    }
    println!("The longest string is {}", result);
}

fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

When I run the example I do get an error.

However when I run the following with the same longest function

```
fn main() {
        let str1 = "abcd";
        let result;
        {
        let str2 = "xyzsdfsdf";
        result = longest(str1, str2);
        }
        println!("{result}");
}
```

I do not get an error and the program executes successfully. I want to know what is actually happening behind the scenes. Why is it that when I give the &str to the longest function this way it still prints the result, even though str2 is supposed to go out of scope after the inner block. According to my understanding, result should get the lifetime of str2 (shortest between str1 and str2) and therefore the value referenced by result should not be valid outside the inner block.

Comment: Try as a point of comparison: `let str2 = String::from(""xyzsdfsdf").as_str()`

Comment: One way to think of string literals is like other data such as numerical constants, being baked into the executable. They're not variables, and they can't fall out of scope. They are never created or dropped. `let str1 = "..."` just assigns a reference to data that permanently exists, hence `'static`. If you're coming from JavaScript or Python where each instance of a string is a separate thing, that might cloud your thinking here. Rust behaves a lot more like C in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

String literals like `"abcd"` are special, because they have the `'static` lifetime. You can check that this is the case by explicitly writing the type and lifetime:

```
    let str1: &'static str = "abcd";
```

Therefore, `'a` in `longest` is inferred to be `'static`, and there is no problem.